# Is "noindex" applied to child content?

Tags: search, crawling, html

When you add the `noindex` class to a div, is all content below it excluded from search crawls?  For example, if I had the code below:

```
<div class="noindex">
   Some Data
   <div> will this be indexed</div>
</div>
```

Will the second `div` be indexed?

Comment: It **should** not be indexed. However I'm waiting for someone to try this ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Accord to [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/06/07/control-search-indexing-crawling-within-a-page-with-noindex.aspx) on msdn blogs, the nested div will not be excluded in SharePoint Search, but also states that it might change.
So my rule is:
  - if you don't want it searched then give it the noindex class.
  - if you want it searched then place it outside the noindex div.